# A mathematical game: moving tiles

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, puzzle

There is a mathematical game called moving tiles.

There are $8$ different movable tiles on a $3 \times 3$ board,

At the beginning the tiles' location is given as following:

```
-------------------
|  1  |  2  |  3  |
-------------------
|  5  |  6  |  7  |
-------------------
|  8  |  9  |     |
-------------------
```

Each time you can only move one tile to the blank, which is next to the blank.

As an example, the fist move must be one of the following situations:

```
-------------------
|  1  |  2  |  3  |
-------------------
|  5  |  6  |     |
-------------------
|  8  |  9  |  7  |
-------------------
```

or

```
-------------------
|  1  |  2  |  3  |
-------------------
|  5  |  6  |  7  |
-------------------
|  8  |     |  9  |
-------------------
```

I want to prove that the following situation is impossible according to the rules:

```
-------------------
|  1  |  2  |  3  |
-------------------
|  5  |  6  |  7  |
-------------------
|  9  |  8  |  0  |
-------------------
```

Maybe I should use graph theory or group theory, can anyone help?

Comment: Maybe you're interested in [What is the parity of permutation in the 15 puzzle?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/635188/19341)...

Comment: See also: [How to check if a 8-puzzle is solvable?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293527/how-to-check-if-a-8-puzzle-is-solvable)