# The Fifteen Puzzle and $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

I was studying permutation groups from the book "*Abstract Algebra and Applications*" by Karlheinz Spindler in which page 553 I came across the following interesting problem. It is on the famous "The Fifteen Puzzle" for which I am unable to upload the picture but rather I would try to use mathematical notation.

Imagine the fifteen puzzle grid is being presented by the following $4\times 4$ matrix given by 
$$\left[\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
9 & 10 & 11 & 12\\
13 & 15 & 14 & \circ 
\end{matrix}\right]$$
where $\circ$ is the empty place in the grid. We can slid the "numbered tiles" through blank space and are supposed to bring down the final structure as 
$$\left[\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
9 & 10 & 11 & 12\\
13 & 14 & 15 & \circ 
\end{matrix}\right]$$

Now the questions are 
[image]

Can some one tell me exactly what am I supposed to do now to solve the problem ?

Comment: Older post: [What is the parity of permutation in the 15 puzzle?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/635188/what-is-the-parity-of-permutation-in-the-15-puzzle)

Comment: There are also post on 8 puzzle: [How to check if a 8-puzzle is solvable?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293527/how-to-check-if-a-8-puzzle-is-solvable)

Comment: The book (at least [this edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=DIjlJ7sJgRYC&pg=PA508)) also says: "Hint. Use (22.12)(e)." This is the claim that: "If $n\ge3$  then $\mathrm{Alt}_n$ is generated by all cycles $(1,2,k)$ with $3 \le k \le n$."

Comment: The non-accepted answer to the older post contains some useful information for this question, but this question is *not* a duplicate (despite two votes to close it as such).

Comment: The first task is to understand what it means for permutations in $S_n$ (or more specifically in $S_{15}$) to be "even".  I can't tell if defining this for the OP is part of "tell me exactly what am I supposed to do now to solve the problem".

Comment: I know what is $S_n$ but after going through the entire question, I was blank to understand the situation. So I post here for help