# Hint on the Fifteen (Slide Puzzle) Problem?

Tags: puzzle, invariance

I've been working on The Fifteen puzzle, which is to transform the slide puzzle in configuration $A$ below into configuration $B$, but I'm unsure how to proceed. Can someone provide a small hint as to what the right direction to investigate would be?

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
13 & 15 & 14
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
B = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
13 & 14 & 15
\end{bmatrix}
$$

**What I tried so far**

My guess is that this is impossible, and the idea is to find an invariant s/t the value for $A$ is different from that of $B$. Some of the things that I tried:

- Coloring the board with alternating colors but didn't find anything useful.
- Looked at sums mod 2 for each row and each column. We can get $A$ and $B$ to match if we consider swapping sums in this case.
- All items in the matrix mod 2, but wasn't sure where to go further with this.

I haven't been able to use the fact that we can only swap with the position of the blank square. Can someone provide a **hint** (not a solution) of what the right direction to go in is? [This other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1328753/the-fifteen-puzzle-and-s-n?noredirect=1) may be similar, but it seems like it discusses the solution, so I've not looked at it.

Comment: It should be useful to check out this Numberphile video: https://youtu.be/YI1WqYKHi78

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle#Solvability) gives you an invariant that should work.

Comment: **First hint:** call the blank square a number as well, say $16$.  Now, consider each game state as some permutation of the $16$ numbers with the original starting state as the identity permutation.  How might you describe going from one game state to another then in the language of permutations?

Comment: **Second hint:** If the blank tile started at the bottom right, after some number of moves it ended at the bottom right, what can you say about the total number of moves made?